# Thick footer causing slide box missing bottom

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to change the height of Ionic footer and use slide box. But Slide box implementation doesn't allow changing footer height.

This is the normal height. You can see the bottom text:

[image]

This is when I increased the height and if I scroll to bottom, the text is **underneath the thick footer**:

[image]

So how I change the dimension of the slide box so that it's offset on bottom to account for the new footer height?

My code: http://codepen.io/hawkphil/pen/Bybmgg

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Test</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="ionicApp" animation="slide-left-right-ios7" ng-controller="SlideController">
    <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-positive">
  <h1 class="title">Dynamic Slides</h1>
</ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content has-header="true" has-footer="true">
<ion-slide-box active-slide="myActiveSlide">
  <ion-slide>
    <div class="box blue"><h1>BLUE</h1></div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x500">
    <p>This text is not showing</p>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <div class="box yellow"><h1>YELLOW</h1></div>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <div class="box pink"><h1>PINK</h1></div>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
    </ion-content>

    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-dark thick-footer">
  <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
</ion-footer-bar>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('SlideController', function($scope) {

  $scope.myActiveSlide = 1;

})
```

**CSS:**

```
.slider-slide {
  padding-top: 80px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;

  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 300;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}

.thick-footer {
  height: 90px!important;
}
```